# How to install Vowpal Wabbit on Amazon EC2 or SageMaker? (amazon linux)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker, vowpalwabbit, amazon-linux

Can someone explain or help me install [vowpalwabbit](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/tree/master/python) (I'm interested in the python bindings) on an Amazon linux machine, either EC2 or SageMaker?
for some reason it is very hard and I can't find anything about it online...

a `pip install vowpalwabbit` returns a

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/5a/9fcd64fd52ad22e2d1821b2ef871e8783c324b37e2103e7ddefa776c2ed7/vowpalwabbit-8.8.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: vowpalwabbit
  Building wheel for vowpalwabbit (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0]= '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tvp1174t/vowpalwabbit/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tvp1174t/vowpalwabbit/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-x0j85ac_ --python-tag cp36
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tvp1174t/vowpalwabbit/
```

lower in the error I can also see a:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2100 (message):
    Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

    Boost version: 1.53.0

    Boost include path: /usr/include

    Could not find the following Boost libraries:

            boost_python3

    Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
    need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
    BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
    to the location of Boost.
```

Comment: Were you successful? I have spent an awful lot of time on this and haven't been able to get it work on Amazon linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested again 1.5 years later, and a `pip install vowpalwabbit` works fine on notebook instance. In training job, adding vowpalwabbit in a `requirements.txt` send to an AWS-managed Scikit learn container (`141502667606.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-scikit-learn:0.23-1-cpu-py3`) also installs successfully. Both tested with vowpalwabbit-8.11.0

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the SageMaker VW Docker image has the Python bindings already installed. See [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-rl-container/blob/master/vw/docker/8.7.0/Dockerfile).

Based on their [container repo](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-rl-container), the image is:

```
462105765813.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-rl-vw-container:vw-8.7.0-cpu
```